# Problemas com paginação no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paginação

Tenho uma página onde é listado o título de todas as noticias do site, e possui paginação.

Me pediram para colocar um campo de pesquisa, para facilitar a busca por uma determinada notícia.

Consegui fazer esse formulário e a implementação do *controller*, mas o problema é o seguinte: eu digito algo para filtrar. Aparece certinho, mas ao ir para outra página (pela paginação), perde esse filtro.

Segue como eu fiz:

O Controller

```
public function noticias()
{
    $texto=Input::get('texto');
    $noticias_geral = Noticia::where('ativa','s')
                        ->whereHas('unidades', function($q){
                                    $q->where('not_noticia_unidade.id_unidade', 1);
                                  })
                        ->Where('texto','like','%'.$texto.'%')
                        ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
                        ->paginate(15);

    return view('pages_home.noticias')->with('noticias_geral',$noticias_geral);
}
```

A rota:

```
Route::any('/noticias', 'NoticiasController@noticias');
```

o HTML:

```
@foreach ($noticias_geral as $key=> $dados)
   <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="linhas_noticia">
             {{ $dados->data->format('d/m/Y') }} - <a href="{!! url('noticia/'.$dados->id_noticias)!!}">{{ $dados->titulo }}</a>
         </div>   
   </div> 
@endforeach
.....................
<div class="col-lg-12">
   {!! $noticias_geral->links() !!}
</div>
```

O que fiz de errado?

Comment: O campo `texto` do filtro é enviado por GET ou POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça as seguintes alterações:

***No Controller***

É resgatado o valor `$texto`, então, precisa dar um [appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) na [paginação para ter o efeito nas outras paginas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination), envie o valor para a sua `View`, ***exemplo***:

```
public function noticias()
{
    $texto = Input::get('texto');
    $noticias_geral = Noticia::where('ativa','s')
                        ->whereHas('unidades', function($q){
                            $q->where('not_noticia_unidade.id_unidade', 1);
                        })
                        ->where('texto','like','%'.$texto.'%')
                        ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
                        ->paginate(15);

    return view('pages_home.noticias')
                  ->with('noticias_geral',$noticias_geral)
                  ->with('texto', $texto);
}
```

***Na View***

Na sua `View` antes de imprimir os `links()`, coloque um método [appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) que é recebe um `array` de variáveis contidas nessa paginação, ***exemplo***:

```
@foreach ($noticias_geral as $key=> $dados)
   <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="linhas_noticia">
            {{ $dados->data->format('d/m/Y') }} 
             - 
            <a href="{!! url('noticia/'.$dados->id_noticias)!!}">
                {{ $dados->titulo }}
            </a>
         </div>   
   </div> 
@endforeach
.....................
<div class="col-lg-12">
   {!! $noticias_geral->appends(['texto' => $texto])->links() !!}
</div>
```

e com isso a paginação vai conter os filtros enviados para todas as paginas.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Database: Pagination](http://Database:%20Pagination)
- [Paginating Query Builder Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results)
- [Displaying Pagination Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: Era isso mesmo @VirgilioNovic!! Valeu!!

Comment: @GiselePassoni se puder aceite como resposta do pergunta